# Use for loop to count occurrences of strings from csv in a text and store as new column in bash

Tags: bash, csv, for-loop, grep

I have a list of names in CSV. I also have a chat file as a txt, that shows the person's name every time they send a message. I am trying to count how many times their name shows up in the chat and loop through the whole list of names.

When I try the for loop:

```
names=$(cat nameslist.csv | cut -d ',' -f1)
for n in $names; do
  count=$(grep $n chat.txt | wc -l)
done
echo $count
```

My $count output is just "1" so I assume something went wrong in the for loop and only displays that last value.

What am I doing wrong?

Ultimately I want to create a csv that has a column of their names and their occurrences ($count) in chat.

Comment: You're printing the count of the last name only.

Comment: Be aware that, depending on your file-structure, you might end up with false positives. Imagine _name2_ is gossiping about _name1_ and your file `chat.txt` contains the message. Then the `grep` will match _name1_ also in the line of _name2_. If we know how your `chat.txt` looks like. We could come up with a good method to parse your files. Also if you have a nam `Bob` and in the chat there is `Bobejaan`, you will have a false positive.

Comment: how many names are in `nameslist.csv`? what's the expected output from your script? a count for each name? a total count for all names? the count for the last name (as Benjamin's mentioned)? please provide sample data from `nameslist.csv`, sample chat message file, and the expected output (to match the sample data from the 2x files)

Comment: If you just want to know how many times a particular name appears in the chat, you can do the following:  `cut -d, -f1 namelist.csv | grep -Fwo -f - chat.txt | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for all your comments. False positives are a minimum because the chat is from me verbally posing a question and the participants writing their answer in chat. The chat.txt file looks like this:  

00:00:09.000 --> 00:00:09.900
<v name1>message contents 

00:05:29.000 --> 00:05:29.900
<v name2>message contents like hello how are you?

with a blank line between the time stamp and message contents of each new message. 

there are 65 names-expected output is a count of each of the 65 names

I just tried that line but my output is the number 1 beside everyone's name